# How can I get generic type of PsiClassReferenceType

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

```java
public class RestControllerExample {
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Test<String, Integer> req() {
        return null;
    }
    
    static class Test<T, V> {
        
        private T fieldT;

        private V fieldV;

        public T getFieldT() {
            return fieldT;
        }
        
        public void setFieldT(T fieldT) {
            this.fieldT = fieldT;
        }

        public V getFieldV() {
            return fieldV;
        }

        public void setFieldV(V fieldV) {
            this.fieldV = fieldV;
        }
    }
}
```

PsiClassReferenceType is `Test<String, Integer>`. How can I know `fieldT` is `String` and `fieldV` is `Integer`?

`class Test<T, V>` just a demo, I can't use the `getParameters()` method to get the type because the order of the fields is not fixed. It is possible that `fieldT` is declared after `fieldV`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field.getType().substitute(classReferenceType.resolveGenerics().getSubstitutor())` should do the job.

1. `fieldT.getType()` in your example must return `T`
2. `classReferenceType.resolveGenerics()` (returns a pair of class and its substitutor), in your example `Test` and `T -> String, V -> Integer`
3. method substitute would replace T in the type with a String, V with an Integer

Comment: psiClass.getFields()[0].getType().substitute(substitutor); 
method substitute not found.

Comment: Sorry, must be `classReferenceType.resolveGenerics().getSubstitutor().substitute(fieldT.getType())` instead, see (3)